# VSCode not reading Cyrillic from console

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java.util.scanner

Well, here is the problem, I have started using VScode, and I can't read from console cyrillic characters.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in,  "UTF-8");
      String word = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Now when I enter any cyrillic string it will print empty string back to me. If i write something like

```
System.out.println("Привет"); //cyrillic symbols
```

It will print "Привет", which is fine. So I am guessing it has something to do with reading the string rather than outputing it.

chcp command gives `Active code page: 65001`

I have tried setting encoding and without it, but it doesn't seem to work, is there something I missed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the code on my machine and got the same result: nothing shown;

You can see, when run it in external Window PowerShell or Command Prompt, the result is different but still not shown correctly:
[image]

When we change the encode style to GBK(936), the cyrillic characters can be displayed correctly:

[image]

When it comes to changing integrated terminal encoding style in vscode and execute code again, it still shows nothing:
[image]

About these different results between external Command Prompt and integrated terminal in VS Code, I've put a [github request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108993). And I'm doing some research, if any useful imformation i get, i will update you.